# Cannot test laravel command when run with PHPUnit

Tags: laravel, command-line, phpunit

I am trying to run Laravel Command with PHPUnit like this　↓

```
    public function testHandle(): void
    {
        Notification::fake();

        // run command
        exec('php artisan command:send_notification --env=local');

        Notification::assertSentTo(XXXXXX, SendNotificatioin::class);
    }
```

process works good, has output log, notification has sent.
but coverage was 0% and process won't pause at breakpoint.

is there any other why to execute Command in PHPUnit?
Thanks

Comment: Assuming it's Laravel 9: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/console-tests

Comment: It is better to use the following code to test Artisan commands instead exec
`$this->artisan('inspire')->assert......`

Comment: @yorukim it is very important that you always refer to the documentation (version specific) to see what is the framework capable of and what does it offer related to tests. As another user stated, you can use [`$this->artisan(...)`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/console-tests#success-failure-expectations)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```php
$this->artisan('send_notification');
```

You can read more about this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/console-tests)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Artisan::call('command:send_notification', ['--env=local'])`